# File sharing violation error for SSCE 3.5

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am trying to use my application on a network.  The database is in SSCE 3.5.  When run at the same time on two different computers, it gives File Sharing violation.  Please advise how to resolve this issue?

Also If I move to SQL Sever Express, is there any way that user does not have to install SQL Server Express, like for SSCE 3.5, we just copy 7 dll files and that's all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing SQL Server Compact files over the network is not possible. Only solution is to use SQL Server (Express) instead. And SQL Server Express must be installed on a machine somewhere. (Or you could consider SQL Azure, no install required)

Comment: Thanks! Can I use SQL Azure with my current connections and is it free?

Comment: Depends on your schema - and it is not free

Comment: I have found: The number of simultaneous connections to a database is limited by the number and amount of resources available, such as the fixed-size session table, which limits the number of simultaneous connections to a maximum of 256 connections.